# MySQL error: What is wrong with my syntax for ranking?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, sql-rank

My MySQL version is 5.6.
I have a MySQL query that I getting error and need help to understand what I am doin wrong.

Here is the query:

```
select images.thumbnail16x9_file,
       images.square_file,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY images.timestamp desc) rank
from images 
where images.media_id = 875021;
```

This is the error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY images.timestamp ) rank
>   from images where images.media' at line 3

I get result back if I do:

```
select images.thumbnail16x9_file,
       images.square_file
from images 
where images.media_id = 875021 ;
```

Any insight?

Comment: Is your MySQL version is 8+ ?

Comment: no the version is  5.6. Just added that info the description. Thank you

Comment: MySQL added support for Window functions only in 8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you mentioned running MySQL 5.6, I compared the documentation for 5.6 with that of 8.0 and noticed that the RANK() function might not be available in MySQL 5.6.

The documentation for MySQL 5.6 exists [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/), and for 8.0 exists [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/).

Searching for the RANK() function in 8.0 returns a section called Window Function Descriptions that seems to cover the RANK() function, while performing the same search in 5.6 doesn't seem to return anything about the function. I'm not 100% sure about this, but would definitely try to find a reference to the RANK() function in the 5.6 documentation for clarification.

Comment: `PARTITION BY <expression>[{,<expression>...}]` is not required.. can be written as `SELECT
    val,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY val
    ) my_rank
FROM
    t;` [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/)

Comment: Great comment! I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

The alias rank is a reserved word in Mysql, so you should choose another name for it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).